# Resolve Rounding Errors while Resizing Controls on Winform

Tags: controls, resize, rounding

I have a requirement to resize all the controls on a form when my form resizes.
Unfortunately, due to some issues I can not use any container control or make use of anchor/dock property. I need to do everything using code.
I am able to resize the controls as per the ratio the screen is resized. While performing this resizing, I need to calculate the new position of all the controls along with there new size. The issue is while calculating these new points I am getting the new values in decimal and if I round them then it is causing the problems and calculating wrong size and position each time I resize my form.
I saw some third party controls for the same task but they all calculate the position exactly.

Please help me resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance,
Ashish Sharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this C#/Windows Forms?

Manual scaling is a pain in the neck.  Realistically the only way to completely prevent any major rounding errors over the long-term lifetime of a form is to store the original locations and sizes of every control that you reposition/resize, and make all your reposition/resize code relative to the original position as opposed to the current position.

You'll end up with some fugliness like this:

```
public class Form1
{
    private Size originalFormSize;

    private List<Control> controlsToResize = new List<Control>();
    private List<Point> originalLocations;
    private List<Size> originalSizes;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SaveOriginalSizes();
    }

    private void SaveOriginalSizes()
    {
        originalFormSize = Size;
        controlsToResize.Add(panel1);
        controlsToResize.Add(panel2);
        ...
        originalLocations = new List<Point>(controlsToResize.Count);
        originalSizes = new List<Size>(controlsToResize.Count);
        foreach (Control c in controlsToResize)
        {
            originalLocations.Add(c.Location);
            originalSizes.Add(c.Size);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);
        float scaleX = (float)originalFormSize.Width / Size.Width;
        float scaleY = (float)originalFormSize.Height / Size.Height;
        for (int i = 0; i < controlsToResize.Count; i++)
        {
            Control c = controlsToResize[i];
            UpdatePosition(c, originalLocations[i], scaleX, scaleY);
            UpdateSize(c, originalSizes[i], scaleX, scaleY);
        }
    }
}
```

...Where obviously you would have to implement the `UpdatePosition` and `UpdateSize` methods on your own - I'm assuming you already have some sort of implementation.

Honestly, it's pretty god-awful.  I would **strongly** recommend that instead of trying to do any of this, you **revisit whatever requirements/design constraints are preventing you from using the `Anchor` and `Dock` properties.**  In all my years, I don't think I've ever heard of a legitimate reason for not using either these or the layout controls `TableLayoutPanel`/`FlowLayoutPanel` or both.  Those are **the way** to deal with layouts in WinForms; anything else is a clumsy hack.

Comment: Hi Aaronaught,
Thanks for your reply.
I can understand that using anchor and dock is the easiest way out there but can't use the same :(
Anyways, I will try to save the initial positions of the controls and will calculate as per those positions. I will let you know the results once I implement that.